# Show 'n.d.' in Bibliography and text

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, mendeley

I use Mendeley and the Overleaf version of LaTeX. The problem is that when I have a Website as a reference I want the output text to be author, n.d. when there are no date, but I get the output of only the author. How do I get Mendeley/Overleaf to show author, n.d.?

I use the type 'book' because Mendeley/overleaf does not support the function of date accessed yet.

In Mendeley I tried typing in n.d. but it returns out an empty lot instead.

[image]

In my Bibtex is there no year entered when I compile:

```
@book{EUVandrammedirektiv,
title = {{EU's vandrammedirektiv}},
author = {{Milj{\o}- og F{\o}devareministeriet}},
publisher = {Date Accessed: 20-04-2020},
url = {https://mst.dk/natur-vand/natur/international-naturbeskyttelse/eu-direktiver/eus-vandrammedirektiv/}}
```

And when I use the citep:

```
\citep{Nitrathandlingsplanen}
```

It returns:

[image]

And my Bibliography:

[image]

I have 4 references with this author and no date, that's why it gives the 'a' in the end.

In my preamble for references:

```
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Off-topic: You should probably (a) replace `publisher = {Date Accessed: 20-04-2020},` with `note = {Date Accessed: 20-04-2020},` and (b) change the entry type from `@book` to `@misc`.

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf helpdesk for advice on how to force Mendeley to accept `n.d.` as a valid value for the `year` field?

Comment: (I'm from Overleaf Support team) @Mico Unfortunately we have no control over what Mendeley allows or not; Overleaf just connects to Mendeley API to fetch the BIB file. I would suggest to contact Mendeley directly about this.

Comment: @yo' - Hi Tomas!

Comment: @Mico I use harvard as a reference style.  And I cannot change the mendeley outpu Bibtex, so that is not an option.

Comment: @yo' I have not contacted them about this issues since I thought it was something else that was the problem, but I will contact them about this issue.

Comment: @MichelleQuach - If Mendeley refuses to change the entry type from `@book` to `@misc`, refuses to enter `n.d.` in the `year` field,  and insists on putting the date-accessed information into the `publisher` field, there is something utterly, totally, and inexcusably wrong with Mendeley.

Comment: @MichelleQuach — What’s the argument of your dicument’s `\bibliographystyle` instruction?

Comment: @Mico I have been in contact with Mendeley support. They do not support this feature but are working on it to get it fixed. How long it takes I don't know. For the bibliographystyle it says `\bibliographystyle{bibtex/harvard}`

Comment: @Mico I just read somewhere that Mendeley does not support the date-accessed information yet, But I found a way of showing it in the reference list by using `@book` but it doesn't show if I use `@misc`. I think they are trying to work this out as well

Comment: @MichelleQuach - I must confess to harboring very strong doubts about the adequacy and overall usefulness of a software tool that makes its users mis-appropriate (a) the `@book` entry type and (b) the `publisher` field.